# Socket IO Android - how to RECEIVE the message from server and puts it into a TextView

Tags: android, eclipse, sockets, io, socket.io

I'm getting the message send and receive message (on), but I don't know how put this in a TextView. I do not know at what point do I do this : "conversaChat.append(args[0].toString());"

my code is:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
Button btnEnviar;
EditText inputMensagem;
TextView conversaChat;
String mensagem;
private BasicExample BasicExample;
private ChatCallbackAdapter callback;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    btnEnviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    inputMensagem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    conversaChat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    btnEnviar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mensagem = inputMensagem.getText().toString();
            conversaChat.append("usuario diz:" + mensagem+"\r\n");
            inputMensagem.setText("");
            try {
                new BasicExample();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public class BasicExample implements IOCallback {
    private SocketIO socket;


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new BasicExample();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public BasicExample() throws Exception {
        socket = new SocketIO();
        socket.connect("xxxxx", this);

        // Emits an event to the server.
        socket.emit("adduser", "Diego");
        socket.emit("sendchat", mensagem);

        //socket.onMessage("updatechat","teste", mensagem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
        System.out.println("an Error occured");
        socketIOException.printStackTrace();
        //conversaChat.append("desconectado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect() {
        System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
        //conversaChat.append("desconectado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnect() {
        System.out.println("Connection established");
        //conversaChat.append("conectado");
    }

    @Override
    public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {

        Object[] arguments = args;
                String json = arguments[0].toString();
                if(event.equals("updatechat")&& args.length > 0){
            conversaChat.append(arguments[0].toString()+": "+arguments[1].toString());
        }


    }


}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: you know there are several developed and broadly used protocols (and associated libraries, usually) for transmitting messages between users, right?

Comment: yes, this part is everything all right, in my log in android i received messages but when i try put this in TextView reaches only one message and disconnect my chat